# how can I make my tab bar to show active color when the user clicks on it

Tags: flutter, user-interface, cross-platform, flutter-web

I have 4 tabs in a flutter tab bar. I am using a silver App bar and the tab bar is inside the bottom property of the silver app bar. I have 4 containers of different sizes inside SingleChilScrollView. With click on each tab the screen scrolls to the specific container.
I have 3 issues:

1. the first one is when I click on the tab it scroll container a bit more than what I want. I want to display the container top(with text in it)on top of the screen.
2. **the second issue(and the most important) is when I click on the tab it scroll the screen to a specific container but the tab active colour is misbehaving(sometimes it shows the active tab and other time it doesn't).**
3. when I resize the web screen size then the tab is not scrolling to the accurate container location.

let's have a situation, when a user click on the 3rd tab, the expected result will be the tab will be active by showing a blue line and screen will scroll to the 3rd container. the gained result is the screen is scrolled to the 3rd container but the tab active colour(that's blue) is not working properly.

the expected result is:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfBv3.png)

the gained result is:
[gained result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efHKH.png)

you can run the code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollContainerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ScrollContainerPage> createState() => _ScrollContainerPageState();
}

class _ScrollContainerPageState extends State<ScrollContainerPage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<GlobalKey> _globalKey = List.empty(growable: true);
  late final secondContainerPosition;
  late final thirdContainerPosition;
  late final fourthContainerPosition;
  bool initilized = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      _globalKey.add(GlobalKey());
    }
    super.initState();
  }
  getPosition() {
    RenderBox box2 =
        _globalKey[1].currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    Offset position2 = box2.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    if (!initilized) {
      secondContainerPosition = position2.dy;
    }
    RenderBox box3 =
        _globalKey[2].currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    Offset position3 = box3.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    if (!initilized) {
      thirdContainerPosition = position3.dy;
    }

    RenderBox box4 =
    _globalKey[3].currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    Offset position4 = box4.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    if (!initilized) {
      fourthContainerPosition = position4.dy;
    }
    initilized = true;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          floatHeaderSlivers: false,
          headerSliverBuilder:
              (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return  [
              SliverAppBar(
                leadingWidth: 200,
                centerTitle: true,
                //titleSpacing: 0,
                //expandedHeight: 200.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,color: Colors.black,),
                title: !kIsWeb? const Text("About us",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ):
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
                  child: Center(
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1),
                      //maxLines: 5,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                        prefixIconColor: Colors.red,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(118, 118, 128, 1), width: 2),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(118, 118, 128, 1), width: 1.5),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1), width: 1.5),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                actions: kIsWeb?[

                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12,12,80,12),
                    padding: const  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5,horizontal: 30),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(4, 80, 225, 1)),
                    ),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: (){

                      },
                      child: Row(
                        children: const [
                          Icon(Icons.person_outline,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(4, 80, 225, 1),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text('Sign in',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color:  Color.fromRGBO(4, 80, 225, 1),
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]:null,


                floating: !kIsWeb?true: false,
                pinned: true,
                snap: !kIsWeb?true: false,
                      bottom: TabBar(
                          indicatorColor: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1),
                          tabs:  [
                            Tab(icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    getPosition();
                                    _scrollController.animateTo(
                                        _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
                                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.ease);
                                  });

                                },
                                child: const Text('scroll to red container', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)),),
                            Tab(icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    getPosition();
                                    _scrollController.animateTo(secondContainerPosition,
                                        // !kIsWeb ? 1140 : 1000,
                                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.ease);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: const Text('scroll to yellow container', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)),),
                            Tab(icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    getPosition();
                                    _scrollController.animateTo(thirdContainerPosition,
                                        // !kIsWeb ? 3380 : 2000,
                                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.ease);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: const Text('scroll to pink container', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)),),
                            Tab(icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    getPosition();
                                    _scrollController.animateTo(fourthContainerPosition,
                                        // _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.ease);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: const Text('scroll to orange container', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)),),
                          ]
                      ),

              ),
            ];
          },
          body:
              SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        key: _globalKey[0],
                        height: 1000,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: const Text('red container')
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),



                    Container(
                        key: _globalKey[1],
                        height: 1700,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: Text('yellow  Container')
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),




                    Container(
                        key: _globalKey[2],
                        height: 3000,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        child: Text('pink Container')
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),




                    Container(
                      key: _globalKey[3],
                        height: 500,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        child: Text('orange Container'),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),


        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: will anybody suggest me an alternate solution to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: yeah i did testing on your code on 5th dec and found out that it does change but you have to click on a specific position on that particular tab bar

Answer (score 0):

Here I've resolved your issue, you added `GestureDetector` to all the individual tabs which hindered the tap area on the actual `TabBar`, what you needed to do instead was to use `onTap` method of the `TabBar` itself :

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollContainerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ScrollContainerPage> createState() => _ScrollContainerPageState();
}

class _ScrollContainerPageState extends State<ScrollContainerPage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<GlobalKey> _globalKey = List.empty(growable: true);
  late final secondContainerPosition;
  late final thirdContainerPosition;
  late final fourthContainerPosition;
  bool initilized = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      _globalKey.add(GlobalKey());
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  getPosition() {
    RenderBox box2 =
        _globalKey[1].currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    Offset position2 = box2.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    if (!initilized) {
      secondContainerPosition = position2.dy;
    }
    RenderBox box3 =
        _globalKey[2].currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    Offset position3 = box3.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    if (!initilized) {
      thirdContainerPosition = position3.dy;
    }

    RenderBox box4 =
        _globalKey[3].currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    Offset position4 = box4.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    if (!initilized) {
      fourthContainerPosition = position4.dy;
    }
    initilized = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          floatHeaderSlivers: false,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                leadingWidth: 200,
                centerTitle: true,
                //titleSpacing: 0,
                //expandedHeight: 200.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: !kIsWeb
                    ? const Text(
                        "About us",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      )
                    : SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                        child: Center(
                          child: TextField(
                            cursorColor: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1),
                            //maxLines: 5,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                              prefixIconColor: Colors.red,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(118, 118, 128, 1),
                                    width: 2),
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(118, 118, 128, 1),
                                    width: 1.5),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1),
                                    width: 1.5),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                actions: kIsWeb
                    ? [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 80, 12),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 5, horizontal: 30),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: const Color.fromRGBO(4, 80, 225, 1)),
                          ),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Row(
                              children: const [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.person_outline,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(4, 80, 225, 1),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Sign in',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(4, 80, 225, 1),
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]
                    : null,

                floating: !kIsWeb ? true : false,
                pinned: true,
                snap: !kIsWeb ? true : false,
                bottom: TabBar(
                    indicatorColor: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1),
                    onTap: (pos){ //added the onTap function with different functions for different pos values
                      if(pos==0){
                        setState(() {
                          getPosition();
                          _scrollController.animateTo(
                              _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              curve: Curves.ease);
                        });
                      }else if(pos==1){
                        setState(() {
                          getPosition();
                          _scrollController.animateTo(
                              secondContainerPosition,
                              // !kIsWeb ? 1140 : 1000,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              curve: Curves.ease);
                        });
                      } else if(pos==2){
                        setState(() {
                          getPosition();
                          _scrollController.animateTo(
                              thirdContainerPosition,
                              // !kIsWeb ? 3380 : 2000,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              curve: Curves.ease);
                        });
                      } else{
                          setState(() {
                            getPosition();
                            _scrollController.animateTo(
                                fourthContainerPosition,
                                // _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.ease);
                          });
                      }
                    },
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        icon: const Text(
                          'scroll to red container',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        icon: const Text(
                          'scroll to yellow container',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        icon: const Text(
                          'scroll to pink container',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        icon: const Text(
                          'scroll to orange container',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                    key: _globalKey[0],
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: const Text('red container')),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Container(
                    key: _globalKey[1],
                    height: 1700,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: Text('yellow  Container')),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Container(
                    key: _globalKey[2],
                    height: 3000,
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    child: Text('pink Container')),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Container(
                  key: _globalKey[3],
                  height: 500,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: Text('orange Container'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution. I used a package named scrollable_list_tab_scroller:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_list_tab_scroller/scrollable_list_tab_scroller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scrollable List Tab Scroller',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Scrollable List Tab Scroller'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final titles = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"];
  late List<Widget> widgets;

  assignWidgets() {
    widgets = [
      Container(
        height: 500,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 1000,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 2000,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 5000,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    assignWidgets();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ScrollableListTabScroller(
          tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, bool active) =>
              Container(
            width: size.width / 4,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: active
                      ? const Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1)
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                titles[index],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: active
                      ? const Color.fromRGBO(0, 79, 224, 1)
                      : Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          itemCount: titles.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => widgets[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).